# pdb debugger doesn't work in reticulate::repl_python()

Tags: python, debugging, rstudio, pdb

I try to debug my Python script within RStudio IDE using pdb package.
The scripts looks the following:

```
a=1 
breakpoint()
b= 2
c = 5
k = 10
```

When i try to print some output (p a) in the console nothing happens.
If i quit the debugger using the command q the variable displays.
Why the p command do not show any output within debugging mode?

Answer (score 0):

I could also not find a native way to debug python code in RStudio, but used ipdb which is an iterative debugger for python

try:

```
import ipdb
ipdb.set_trace()
```

then run:

```
python -m ipdb Run-Script.py
```

I followed this guide here:
https://hasil-sharma.github.io/2017-05-13-python-ipdb/